# Customizing cache key using class properties for post sharp method caching

Tags: c#, postsharp

I was wondering if its possible to cache TestMethod of class ABC using private string identifier and function input parameter a using postsharp.

```
    public Class ABC {

    private string identifier;

    public ABC(string identifier){

       this.identifier = identifier;

    }

    public int TestMethod(int a){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The cache key also includes `this` value converted to string. So you can override the `ToString()` method of the `ABC` class to include the `identifier`. Or you can create a custom formatter class for `ABC`.

Also, see the following documentation pages for reference:

- http://doc.postsharp.net/caching-keys
- http://doc.postsharp.net/custom-formatter